# Unsupported local android devices for Blazor Maui Application

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

Unsupported any local Android devices for my Blazor Maui Application. How to solve that? But, the Windows app has no problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with this for ages.  It seems the settings for Android appear in two places.   Under >Application and under >Android.
Check under ">Application" and see if that fixes your problem.  It did for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're not targeting API 31? Right-click your .NET MAUI project and click Properties and look for these settings:

[image: Partial screenshot of the .NET MAUI project settings within Visual Studio 2022]

Alternatively, open your .NET MAUI project csproj file and look for any values that have to do with Android. For example:

`<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'">23.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>`

Make sure that you don't exclude API level 31 anywhere.

Comment: I try to do that but, did not hit that change. What is the reason?

Comment: Hi  @sudathG,  have you tried to rebuild your app?

Comment: Yes, I did that @JessieZhang-MSFT

Comment: Hi @sudathG, you can also try to restart your visual studio.